# How to use django-allauth generate_unique_username in custom sign up form?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm trying to generate a unique username from the user's first name as it not used in the sign up form.

I am not sure how to implement allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter in the forms.py module. Please help with an example.

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm, LoginForm
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name', widget=forms.TextInput(
attrs={'placeholder': 'First name', 'class': 'form-control'}))
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name', widget=forms.TextInput(
attrs={'placeholder': 'Last name', 'class': 'form-control'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

def signup(self, request, user):
    adapter = get_adapter()
    username = adapter.generate_unique_username(self, self.cleaned_data['first_name'])
    user.username = username
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.save()
```